# Update global dict initialized in module 1 using function from module 2 based on same dict

Tags: python, module, global

I am running into some trouble with global variables declared inside a module, that I then need to both a) update in the main script and b) use as a basis for this updating in another module. I haven't been able to find any other topics with quite the same question/module structure, so I hope someone will be able to help me.

To clarify, a simplified version of the code:

**main.py**

```
import initialAB
import updateAB
import util

def fun1(iterate, argsList):
    initialAB.init(a, b) # Initializes A and B
    print(A, B)

    # PROBLEM: 
    A, B, x = updateAB.update() 
    # I can't update A and B without first declaring them global variables
    # but if I do so, print(A, B) yields: "name 'A' is not defined"

    while iterate:
        x_old = x
        A, B, x = updateAB.update()
        if x_old == x:
            arg1 = False
            util.write_to_file() # write final version A and B to file
            print(fun2(argslist[0], argslist[1]))

fun1(True, someList)
```

**initialAB.py**

```
A = dict()
B = dict()

def get_dict(arg2, arg3):
    if arg3 == A:
        A = # something to initialize A
    elif arg3 == B:
        B = # something to initialize B

def init(a, b):
    global A, B
    get_dict(a, "A")
    get_dict(b, "B")
```

**updateAB.py**

```
import initialAB
from initialAB import A, B

def fun2(someArg, otherArg):
    # c and d calculated based on someArg, otherArg, but also A and B
    return c, d

def update():
    c, d = fun2(someArg, otherArg)
    # use c and d to calculate some new version of A and B
    newA = # something something
    newB = # etc.
    return newA, newB, newX
```

Previously, I just wrote the updated A and B to a file inside updateAB.update(). But in order to update A and B in main.py and then use and update them in subsequent iterations, I need to declare them as global variables. However, if I do that, I can no longer access the A and B as initialized by initialAB.init(a, b).

Most of this probably could have been prevented by simply returning A and B from initialAB.init(), which is what I would've done. Unfortunately, I didn't write most of that and A and B are used in way too many other functions that I do not want to change, so I'm really hoping someone has another solution to fix this. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a script which declares a variabale, you can use the variable simply as `myscript.myvar` in any other script that imported the script. Usually this is done in a separate script that doesn't do anything other than declaring the variables. You could have functions, e.g. use your `initialAB` for this but usually it's neater to have one script just for variables because you'll have to import that everywhere else and might not always need those functions.

I won't go over everything but just to demonstrate what it generally looks like:

#### params.py

```
A = dict()
B = dict()
# Declare any variables you want share across scripts.
# Even placeholders will do since you can just overwrite their values:
x = 0
y = None
```

#### main.py

```
import params
import initialAB
import updateAB
import util

def fun1(iterate, argsList):
    params.A, params.B = initialAB.init(a, b) # Initializes A and B
    # Note: I changed it so that init has to return A and B. 
    # You could also change init to use params.var (for example)
    print(params.A, params.B)

    # PROBLEM: 
    params.A, params.B, x = updateAB.update() 
    # I can't update A and B without first declaring them global variables
    # but if I do so, print(A, B) yields: "name 'A' is not defined"

    while iterate:
        x_old = x
        params.A, params.B, x = updateAB.update()
        if x_old == x:
            arg1 = False
            util.write_to_file() # write final version A and B to file
            print(fun2(argslist[0], argslist[1]))

fun1(True, someList)
```

Basically you just have to re-write your variable references from `var` to `params.var` and it should work.

An alternative approach, if you're not familiar with it, is to use a class. Essentially you could turn your main script into a class, which carries with it definitions of your shared variables. Other scripts could then use those variables as `myclass.myvar`, which is pretty much the same in terms of syntax. It would also avoid having to have that extra `params` script.

#### main.py

```
# imports

class mainclass():

    def __init__(self):
        # This code is run when you first call your class
        self.A = dict() # Some variable declarations 
        self.B = dict()
        self.fun1(True, someList)

    # All function calls inside the class refer to self.functionname
    # For variables this depends: If you use a variable only inside 
    # a function, you don't need it. If you do (like A and B), you must.
    # self.var is an attribute of a class that persists even after the 
    # function that declared it exits. The other variables are cleared away.

    def fun1(self, iterate, argsList): # First argument is always self
        self.A, self.B = initialAB.init(a, b) # Initializes A and B
        print(self.A, self.B)

        self.A, self.B, self.x = updateAB.update() 

        while iterate:
            x_old = self.x
            self.A, self.B, self.x = updateAB.update()
            if x_old == self.x:
                arg1 = False
                util.write_to_file() # write final version A and B to file
                print(fun2(argslist[0], argslist[1]))

main = mainclass()
# Other scripts can refer to variables in mainclass as main.variable
# e.g.: main.A, main.B
```